# Trying to get property of non-object yii2 ADMINLTE

Tags: yii2

mi problema es el siguiente, estoy trabajando con yii2 y con el modo basic en el main cuando quería que cierto perfil viera ciertas pestañas lo hacia de la siguiente manera

```
if(Yii::$app->user->identity->perfil_id == "1")
```

y me funcionaba perfecto.

Ahora le agregue el AdminLTE y el menu funciona de diferente manera y al poner el codigo

```
if(Yii::$app->user->identity->perfil_id == "1")
```

Me dice:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Cuando uso:

```
if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
```

no me da error, pero el problema es que tengo mas de un perfil.

Comment: Tú modelo que implementa _Identity_ ¿tiene la propiedad ```perfil_id```?

Comment: si, si la tiene lo que me extraña es que cuando uso yii2 basic el theme que viene por defecto, me funciona perfecto pero cuando le añadi el adminlte no me deja usar eso